How to keep function call attributes consistent in lapply and Map?
I want to attach the function call as an attribute. While using fn() directly works fine, when I run it inside lapply(), it returns X[[i]] instead of the actual name passed to the d= parameter. I expect to see df1 and df2 as the output, not X[[i]].
> fn <- \(d, x=x, y=999, ...) {
+   cl <- match.call()
+   fa <- formals(fn)
+   fa[length(fa)] <- NULL
+   ma <- setdiff(names(fa), names(cl))
+   cl[ma] <- fa[ma]
+   cl[-c(1, 2)] <- lapply(cl[-c(1, 2)], eval, envir=parent.frame())
+   # cl$d <- quote(d)
+   res <- d[[1]]  ## so `res` depends on `d`
+   attr(res, 'call') <- cl
+   return(res)
+ }
> 
> z. <- 777
> df1 <- lst$df1
> df2 <- lst$df2
> fn(df1, x=666, z=z.)
[1] 1 2 3
attr(,"call")
fn(d = df1, x = 666, z = 777, y = 999)
> lapply(list(df1=df1, df2=df2), fn, x=666, z=z.)
$df1
[1] 1 2 3
attr(,"call")
FUN(d = X[[i]], x = 666, z = 777, y = 999)

$df2
[1] 1 2 3
attr(,"call")
FUN(d = X[[i]], x = 666, z = 777, y = 999)

This obviously relates to an earlier question, so I tried Map as proposed, however, apparently it doesn't generalize well.
> Map(list(df1=df1, df2=df2), f=fn, x=666, z=z.)
$df1
[1] 1 2 3
attr(,"call")
(\(d, x=x, y=999, ...) {
  cl <- match.call()
  fa <- formals(fn)
  fa[length(fa)] <- NULL
  ma <- setdiff(names(fa), names(cl))
  cl[ma] <- fa[ma]
  cl[-c(1, 2)] <- lapply(cl[-c(1, 2)], eval, envir=parent.frame())
  # cl$d <- quote(d)
  res <- d[[1]]
  attr(res, 'call') <- cl
  return(res)
})(d = dots[[1L]][[2L]], x = 666, z = 777, y = 999)

$df2
[1] 1 2 3
attr(,"call")
(\(d, x=x, y=999, ...) {
  cl <- match.call()
  fa <- formals(fn)
  fa[length(fa)] <- NULL
  ma <- setdiff(names(fa), names(cl))
  cl[ma] <- fa[ma]
  cl[-c(1, 2)] <- lapply(cl[-c(1, 2)], eval, envir=parent.frame())
  # cl$d <- quote(d)
  res <- d[[1]]
  attr(res, 'call') <- cl
  return(res)
})(d = dots[[1L]][[2L]], x = 666, z = 777, y = 999)

Then I tried to do cl$d <- quote(d), cl$d <- quote(substitute(d)), cl$d <- quote(eval(parse(text=d))), cl$d <- quote(get(d)), as commented out above, to no avail. Here result of cl$d <- quote(d) version:
> fn(df1, x=666, z=z.)
[1] 1 2 3
attr(,"call")
fn(d = d, x = 666, z = 777, y = 999)
> lapply(list(df1=df1, df2=df2), fn, x=666, z=z.)
$df1
[1] 1 2 3
attr(,"call")
FUN(d = d, x = 666, z = 777, y = 999)

$df2
[1] 1 2 3
attr(,"call")
FUN(d = d, x = 666, z = 777, y = 999)

Expected output
> lapply(list(df1=df1, df2=df2), fn, x=666, z=z.)
$df1
[1] TRUE
attr(,"call")
FUN(d = df1, x = 666, z = 777, y = 999)

$df2
[1] TRUE
attr(,"call")
FUN(d = df2, x = 666, z = 777, y = 999)

Just a heads up, I'm looking for a solution using base R.
Edit
After @MrFlick's answer, I see I need to clarify. Actually I have a large list lst:
> lst <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2)
> lapply(lst, function(x) 
+   do.call("fn", list(as.name(x), x=666, z=z.))
+ )
Error in as.vector(x, mode = mode) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'symbol'


If lapply() is passed a named list, you can capture the names using sys.call() as e.g. here. It's not pretty though. You'll have to introduce some logic to work out whether the function is being called from lapply() or directly. And I imagine you'll run into difficulty in more complex cases like nested lapply() calls. If at all possible I would try to find a way to modify the function to take the desired name as an argument, or create a wrapper function with an additional argument which does this.

@SamR Interesting. This is close, but gives me d = list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2) in each iteration. Even with Map when passing nm=c('df1', 'df2') and nmm inside fn().

I came up with this solution that uses elements of @MrFlick's answer, to use do.call(), and from the answer to pass the names in Map() quoted in the OP.
We just need to insert one if clause in fn(). In the call fn() we replace d -- if present in the ellipsis -- with certain parameters and attributes, or leave it as it is.
> fn <- function(d, x=666, y=999, z, ...) {
+   cl <- match.call()
+   fa <- formals(fn)
+   fa[length(fa)] <- NULL
+   ma <- setdiff(names(fa), names(cl))
+   cl[ma] <- fa[ma]
+   cl[-c(1, 2)] <- lapply(cl[-c(1, 2)], eval, envir=parent.frame())
+   if (".name" %in% names(list(...))) {
+     .name <- sprintf('%s$%s', attr(d, 'lnm'), list(...)$.name)
+     cl$d <- str2lang(.name)
+     cl$.name <- NULL
+   } 
+   res <- d[[1]]
+   attr(res, 'call') <- cl
+   return(res)
+ }

In the lapply call, we pass the names in a .name parameter that triggers the if clause in fn() as well as the list name using deparse(substitute(.)).
> lapply(names(lst), \(x) {
+   do.call("fn", 
+           list(
+             d=`attr<-`(
+               get(x, envir=as.environment(lst)), 'lnm', deparse(substitute(lst))
+               ), 
+             x=666, y=999, z=z., .name=x)
+   )})
$df1
[1] 1 2 3
attr(,"call")
fn(d = lst$df1, x = 666, y = 999, z = 777)

$df2
[1] 1 2 3
attr(,"call")
fn(d = lst$df2, x = 666, y = 999, z = 777)

This also works for single runs as intended. Both options allow the call to be copied and executed.
> fn(d=df3, x=666, z=z.)
[1] 1 2 3
attr(,"call")
fn(d = df3, x = 666, z = 777, y = 999)
> 
> fn(d=lst$df1, x=666, z=z.)
[1] 1 2 3
attr(,"call")
fn(d = lst$df1, x = 666, z = 777, y = 999)

Limitations
The Map call is not trivial. Also, fn() must be changed, which is not a problem for my use case, since fn() belongs to me, but can lead to problems if it came from a package. Issues may occur if it is used in several nested calls, which has not been tested.

Data:
> lst <- replicate(2, data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4)), simplify=FALSE) |> 
+   setNames(c('df1', 'df2'))
> z. <- 777
> df3 <- lst$df1


You can't pass through variable names though lapply like that. If you want your function to record the invocation and you care about vairable names, a better solution is to build the invocations. Here we can do that with do.call.
lapply(c("df1", "df2"), function(x) 
  do.call("fn", list(as.name(x), x=666, z=z.))
)
# [[1]]
# [1] TRUE
# attr(,"call")
# fn(d = df1, x = 666, z = 777)
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] TRUE
# attr(,"call")
# fn(d = df2, x = 666, z = 777)


Thanks for your answer, looks promising, however I'll run into problems if the list is already packed, please see edit to my question.

@jay.sf. Then lapply over names(lst). But then you aren't actually using the values in the list. The "call" you are creating would not really work. fn(d = df2, x = 666, z = 777) is different from fn(d = lst$df2, x = 666, z = 777) and only the latter would really uses the data in the list and there's no guarantee that lst$df2 matches the data in df2. The list() call creates a lazy copy.

We can really appreciate do.call as a special wrench, +1 for the hint! I'd be curious if this hiccup only exists in R or if also in other languages.
